# Given ${[1+ {(1+ x)}^{1/2}]×\tan(x) = \left[1+ {(1- x)}^{1/2}\right]}$, find $\sin 4 x$.

Tags: trigonometry

If

$${[1+ {(1+ x)}^{1/2}]×\tan(x) = \left[1+ {(1- x)}^{1/2}\right]}$$

then find the value of $\sin(4x)$.

The options given are:

a) $x$

b) $4x$

c) $2x$

I tried applying many trigo identities but none of them is working and the radicals are posing a big problem...need help...Thanks!!

Comment: You've asked 22 questions, answered 14 and being a member of this site for 45 days. I think it is about time you learn the easy directions to properly write mathematics in this site.

Comment: @DonAntonio You should check out [this user](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/117290/alephnull)...45 days seem like nothing compared to the linked user who **never** typesets math properly. I personally feel like there should be some sort of ban after a time, but I highly doubt the community would go for that. Shameful nonetheless.

Comment: Yeah... I completely agree with you guys. Also thanks for those stats @DonAntonio. I appreciate it.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this had a closed form answer.

Comment: Using $\sin 4x=\frac{2u}{1+u^2}$, with $u=\tan 2x$ and then $u=\frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2}$  with $t=\tan x$ gives you the answer... which is not so nice.

Comment: @PaulEnta The given equation has *one* real solution $x \approx 0.6186 \approx 0.1969 \,\pi\;$ so $\sin(4x)$ is *one* real value, not an expression in $x$.

Comment: @dxiv You're right, sorry about that!

Comment: Check out the edited question... the given answer is $x$.

Comment: The answer is x(calculator checks out taking $x=0.61864419684245725314110752758288$). I would try to simplify the expression obtained by @PaulEnta above.

Comment: @SirJMP Next time please post the entire question upfront. It's not as much a matter of *which* of a/b/c is correct, but the fact that the problem was asking for an expression in $x$ i.e. *not* the actual value of $\sin(4x)$.

Comment: @PaulEnta It looks like you guessed right what the question meant to ask after all.

Comment: @DonAntonio Where could I learn more about MathJax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let: $$t = \tan(x) = \frac{1+\sqrt{1-x}}{1+\sqrt{1+x}}$$

Using the double-angle sine and [half-angle tangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula) formulas:

$$
\sin(4x) \;=\; 2\;\sin(2x)\;\cos(2x) \;=\; 2 \cdot \frac{2 t}{1 + t^2} \cdot \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \;=\; \frac{4t(1-t^2)}{(1+t^2)^2}
$$

Substituting back $t$ in terms of $x$ and [simplifying](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+(4+((1%2Bsqrt(1-x))%2F(1%2Bsqrt(1%2Bx)))+(+1+-+((1%2Bsqrt(1-x))%2F(1%2Bsqrt(1%2Bx)))%5E2+))+%2F+(1+%2B+((1%2Bsqrt(1-x))%2F(1%2Bsqrt(1%2Bx)))%5E2)%5E2):

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\sin(4x) & =\; \frac{2 x (\sqrt{1-x^2}+2 \sqrt{1-x}+2 \sqrt{1+x}+3)}{(\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}+2)^2} \\
 & =\; \frac{2 x (\sqrt{1-x^2}+2 \sqrt{1-x}+2 \sqrt{1+x}+3)}{(1-x) + (1+x) + 4 + 2 \sqrt{(1-x)(1+x)} + 4 \sqrt{1-x} + 4 \sqrt{1+x} } \\
 & =\; \frac{\cancel{2} x \bcancel{(\sqrt{1-x^2}+2 \sqrt{1-x}+2 \sqrt{1+x}+3)}}{\cancel{2}\bcancel{(3 + \sqrt{1-x^2} + \sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x})} } \\
 & =\; x
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 5):

For convenience, write
$$ s := \sin x \qquad c := \cos x \qquad m := 1 +\sqrt{1+x} \qquad n := 1 + \sqrt{1-x}$$

The initial equation can then be rewritten as
$$m s = n c \qquad\to\qquad m^2 s^2 = n^2 c^2 \qquad \to\qquad c^2 = \frac{m^2}{m^2+n^2} \qquad s^2 = \frac{n^2}{m^2 + n^2}$$
Note that $m$ and $n$ are both strictly positive. Since (presumably real) $x$ must lie between $1$ and $-1$, we know that $\cos x \geq 0$; since $\tan x$ must be positive in the original equation, $\sin x$ is, too. Thus, we have ...
$$c = \frac{m}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}} \qquad s = \frac{n}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}$$

Now ...

$$\begin{align}
\sin 4x &= 2 \sin 2x \cos 2x \\[4pt]
&= 4 sc ( 2 c^2 - 1 ) \\[4pt]
&= \frac{4mn}{m^2 + n^2} \left(\frac{2 m^2}{m^2 + n^2} - 1\right) \\[4pt]
&= \frac{4mn(m^2-n^2)}{(m^2 + n^2)^2} \\[4pt]
&= \frac{8 x (3 + 2 \sqrt{1 - x} + 2 \sqrt{1 + x} + \sqrt{1 - x} \sqrt{1 + x})}{8 (3 + 2 \sqrt{1 - x} + 2 \sqrt{1 + x} + \sqrt{1 - x} \sqrt{1 + x})} \\[4pt]
&= x
\end{align}$$